# Not making it a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this situation, for example, if `$(this).text()` becomes 0, it will not work since in the switch 0 is not equal to "0".

In my assignment, I cannot remove " " from case.

So basically `$(this).text()` has to become a string somehow. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
...
$( '.xyz' ).click( function()...
  var key = $(this).text();
  switch( key ) {
    case "0":
    case "00":
    case "1":
    case "2":
    case "3":
    case "4":
    case "5":
    case "6":
    case "7":
    case "8":
    case "9":
    ...
```

https://gist.github.com/188d81480a1503d1985b

Comment: You've got unbalanced parentheses near `.text())`. Is all of that supposed to be inside the `click` callback?

Comment: that was only for the example

Comment: Now you're missing a semicolon, so I'm pretty sure something else has been left off too. `text()` should be returning a string.

Comment: my bad again, only example. on Line 29 it is ok: https://gist.github.com/188d81480a1503d1985b

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the function and see what the value really becomes? Really, `text()` ought to be returning text.

Comment: `.text()` **always** returns a string.

Comment: if I set key = "3"; I get what I want but when I set $(this).text(); and it has a value of 3, it will not run through switch

Comment: If I do `caisse.traiterCle(3)` it still works. It's something else with your problem.

Comment: exactly, but that parameter has to be dynamic... that's why I need to use .text() but it doesnt work

Comment: Post an example in which $(this).text() will ever return a non-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var key = String($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you want the numeric value?

```
var key = parseInt($(this).text()); //or
key = parseDouble($(this).text());
```

Edit 2:
Thanks for the suggestion Derek. Always forget that:

```
+$(this).text(); //also converts to integer; parseint can be given a radix (base). + if string is already in the form of a base 10 integer
```

Edit: Also, your code looks wrong; `$(this).text())` has an unbalanced paranthesis. text() always returns a string. Which is why I made the assumption above. Although your question seems to imply you want to search by the result of text()? In that case you would want a string though, which text() gives you.

If you could give us more details and code it'd be easier to understand

Comment: i want it to run in switch, which case values are "x"

Comment: `$(this).text()` should always return a string; documentation: `The result of the .text() method is a string containing...`

Comment: `+$(this).text()` is always better than `parseInt($(this).text())`. Try `parseInt(08)`, it will return `0` instead of `8`.

Comment: I don't see what's the problem `if $(this).text() becomes 0, it will not work since in the switch 0 is not equal to "0".` .text() is always a string. I've done some testing with your code in the js console, and I don't see an error

Comment: if you uncomment line 34, you will see what it is supposed to do in html file.

Comment: but it only works because I gave it "3", but its a static number... that's why I wanted this.text to be there instead so it would change dynamically :(

Comment: I'm having trouble following the code as it's in french :P but it *should* work because "3" is a string, just as `.text()` should be. What happens regularly? **What's the problem**

Comment: :) so when I set "3" straight, and I click on the calculator button, it will show 3 on the display( problem is because 3 is a static string, even tho I press on 1, 2, 4, 5 etc... well, 3 shows up on display.     If I enter $(this).text(); it will not show up since it doesnt match it with switch case ( 3 VS "3" ) thanks!!!

Comment: I'm having trouble following the program because of language - sorry! But you'll have to do some debugging on your own. You're probably selecting the wrong element, because the switch case and .text() intnetion is right

Comment: The question was: So basically $(this).text() has to become a string somehow. Any ideas? This answer converts the text to an int which is the opposite of what he asked for.

Comment: @earlonrails it's always a string, as explained.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
var key = "" + $(this).text();
```

Which will always be a string. IE

```
var b = "" + 0 ;
// b = "0"
```